# Issues while upgrading to Extjs 5.1 from Extjs 4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, upgrade, extjs4.1, extjs5

I have developed application using extjs 4.1. Its working absolutely fine as required. Now i want to upgrade my application using extjs 5.1. I included necessary Extjs 5.1 files in my application. But its failed to load, even not single request is getting send to server. I am facing lots of issues as-

1.Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: data.field.double
This error is appearing for each data type mentioned in model while defining      fields. I observerd Extjs 5.1 examples..In most of it data types are not provided while defining fields in model..So should i need to remove type from model? Is there any other solution for it?

2.Uncaught Error: [Ext.create] Unrecognized class name /alias: X.store.FieldStore

3.[E] [Ext.Loader] Some requested files failed to load.

4.[W] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'X.store.MembersStore'; consider adding Ext.require('X.store.MembersStore') above Ext.onReady

So can someone please guide me,what solutions i need to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The problem is that `double` is not a valid type in ExtJs. ExtJs 4 was permissive and accepted invalid types in field definitions. ExtJs 5 does not.
2. The message seems clear to me. `X.store.FieldStore` is neither a class name nor an alias. Probably the file with the class definition is not loaded.
3. You have to find out.
4. You should require this store where it is needed, e.g. in a controller with `stores: ['X.store.MembersStore']` or with `require: ['X.store.MembersStore']`